# hibernate db2 ignore join on spaces

Tags: hibernate, caching, join, db2

I have a hibernate mapping over a legacy DB2 database. A particular table has a foreign key to another table. This column is populated with spaces instead of null when there is no association to the other table. I have a many to one associate to the second table. The issue is for every row that has spaces in the foreign key field an SQL is executed against the database as there is no value in the cache for it. Is there a way to ignore fields populated with spaces in the join so requests are not issued to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add this condition to the `WHERE` clause (not the join condition)?

```
 WHERE THE_COLUMN <> ' ' AND ...
```